# picturebox image in c sharp

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using these following codes to save picturebox image to database. just i need some code to load picturebox image from database to picturebox.

```
DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        switch (dr)
        {
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                break;
            case DialogResult.OK:
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = sql;
                cmd.CommandText = ("insert [Entry] ([Image]) values (@Image)");
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] image = stream.ToArray();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", image);
                try
                {
                    sql.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                finally
                {
                    sql.Close();
                }
                break;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you googled it? Look into the Image.FromSteam(Stream stream) method.

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225610/i-want-to-load-image-from-the-database-into-a-picture-box-using-loadasync-and-a

Answer (score 0):

here there are both code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25956/Sending-Receiving-PictureBox-Image-in-C-To-From-Mi

button2_Click is used to Retrieve the Image:

```
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection
                     ("Server=.;database=PictureDb;integrated security=true");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
                        ("select fldPic from tblUsers where fldCode=1", connect);
    //for retrieving the image field in SQL SERVER EXPRESS
    //Database you should first bring
    //that image in DataList or DataTable
    //then add the content to the byte[] array.
    //That's ALL!
    SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyImages");

    byte[] MyData = new byte[0];

    dp.Fill(ds, "MyImages");
    DataRow myRow;
    myRow = ds.Tables["MyImages"].Rows[0];

    MyData = (byte[])myRow["fldPic"];

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(MyData);
    //With the code below, you are in fact converting the byte array of image
    //to the real image.
    pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: if i use where i will tell me incorrect syntax near keyword where